# Is there any technologies or considerations about using LWC in an offline mode

Tags: lightning-web-components, offline

I have several LWC's components which connect with each other and handle payment operations.
I want to know if there are any technologies or considerations about ***using*** ***LWC in an offline mode.***

**I have found about   [Progressive Web Apps](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2020/04/how-to-pwa-offline-lwc) .**

[image]

--

However, it not exactly what I am looking for

Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you looking for *Salesforce* LWC to support offline, or just LWC in general?

Comment: @sfdcfox I am looking for Salesforce LWC to support offline.